# Usage de « par contre », « en revanche » et « au contraire »

Tags: usage, locutions

Je souhaite être éclairé concernant l'usage approprié de ces locutions qui sont fort usitées me semble-t-il.

Comment: C'est-à-dire ? Qu'est-ce que tu veux savoir que tu ne trouves pas dans http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contre http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revanche et  http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contraire ?

Comment: Merci, il y a tout et très fouillé. Un ami ayant séjourné en France lors de ses études (à Montbéliard je crois) m'a déconseillé l'utilisation de "par contre", j'ai également noté la préférence marquée pour "en revanche" par une connaissance maîtrisant bien le Français.

Comment: Ah, oui, "par contre" a subit l'ire des puristes (Grevisse en parle dans le Bon usage: §965 e 4°), même si c'est une très ancienne construction, qui est loin d'être toujours remplaçable. Gide en a fourni de superbes exemples, notamment (avec un tel remplacement pour souligner l'incongruité) "Oui, mon frère et mon mari son revenus saufs de la guerre, en revanche j'y ai perdu mes deux fils". Stéphane explique bien la différence de sens qui rend ce remplacement impossible.

Comment: Il semble même que Voltaire à son époque aurait édicté un "fatwa" à ce sujet ???

Comment: Depuis ma plus tendre enfance, on m'a toujours asséné la non-conformité de *par contre* ("juxtaposition incongrue de deux prépositions", "Voltaire lui-même y était opposé"...), ce qui m'a conduit à faire particulièrement attention à sa présence en littérature: je confirme que l'on trouve des *par contre* sous la plume d'à peu près tous les grands écrivains français/francophones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ces locutions sont parfois interchangeables, mais il y a quelques cas typiques où l'une de ces expressions ne pourrait pas être remplacée par une autre.

- *Par contre* est couramment¹ utilisé pour introduire un fait qui va en sens contraire. Par exemple pour préciser qu'une hypothèse émise n'est pas applicable à un cas particulier ou voisin :

  > Il est interdit de fumer à l'intérieur des bars et des restaurants. Par contre, c'est autorisé en terrasse.
- *En revanche* (ou *en contrepartie*) est utilisé pour introduire une phrase qui rétablit un équilibre :

  > Il travaille tard toute la semaine. En revanche, il prend son week-end un jour plus tôt que les autres.
- *Au contraire* annule l'hypothèse précédemment envisagée (qui pouvait déjà être niée ou affaiblie) :

  > Il ne fait pas partie des plus sages. Au contraire, il se pourrait bien qu'il soit l'un des plus dissipés.

—
<sub>1. Voir la [controverse au sujet de *par contre* (page en anglais)](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/par-contre-2/).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

*Par contre* est utilisé pour indiquer un contraste, e.g.

> J'aime les chats.  Par contre, mon frère les déteste.

*En revanche* est similaire mais un peu moins fort, pour indiquer un autre fait.  En anglais on utiliserait le terme « *on the other hand* » ; e.g.

> Les socialistes pensent que trop d'argent est mauvais pour la société.  En revanche, les conservateurs pensent que c'est une bonne chose.

Finalement, *au contraire* porte le même sens qu'en anglais, pour indiquer l'opposé ; e.g.

> Tu penses que je ne peux pas cuisiner ?  Au contraire, ma cuisine est la meilleure dans le monde !

Answer (score 2):

Bien souvent, la richesse de la langue est utilisée pour préciser avec  finesse, la nature détaillée d'une idée, **cependant** bien des orateurs (souvent les politiciens) utilisent cette richesse pour *remplir* (le bocal et *noyer le poisson*, voire [réthorique](/questions/tagged/r%c3%a9thorique) ( [Rhétorique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rh%C3%A9torique) [Rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) : )).

Afin d'éviter de saouler le lecteur, on évitera de répéter les expressions, on cherchera alors à varier, différer, changer…

Ces trois exemples ne sont qu'un petit extrait de ce que la langue française peut offrir aux spécialistes de la langue de bois qui ont besoin de mots pour remplir de répétitions aux allures de nouvelles vérités…

- par contre
- en revanche
- cependant
- au contraire
- par opposition
- alors que
- toutefois
- néanmoins
- pourtant

voire encore:

- sauf que (rarement du plus bel effet, pas de l'excellent françois)
- à l'exception de
- excluant
- à contrario (à ne pas placer trop près d'un *au contraire* :-)
- au demeurant
- à part cela

Je commence à être au bout, ***mais*** je reste ***encore*** persuadé qu'il y'en a beaucoup d'autres…

Comment: *Hormis cela*, peut-être, ou *à part ça*  principalement à l'oral, mais *à part cela*,  ça ne me semble pas habituel (en tout cas en France).

Comment: Merci, il est tard, peut-être un peu flemmard... Pourtant je m'étais relu. :-(

Comment: If modification don't alter original meaning, feel free! (thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

On m'a toujours dit que l'on devait utiliser *en revanche* et non *par contre* dans un discours, dans une argumentation,
... et pourtant j'ai tapé de nombreux rapports  et analyses d'un expert qui tenait à ses *par contre*, contre l'avis de tout le secrétariat.

Sans doute des réminiscences des cours de mathématique qui en font un usage excessif.
*Par contre* peut être latinisé en *'a contrario'* lors d'une démonstration magistrale, d'un raisonnement juridique.

En effet si une situation est [dé]favorable, elle l'est intrinsèquement, elle ne peut pas l'être contre elle-même.

*En revanche* (pour contester, proposer une 'revanche' à l'argumentation que l'on combat, la 'belle' [qui vient après la revanche pour départager une égalité éventuelle lors d'un duel verbal] sera la conclusion retenue) :

> En revanche on peut envisager cette situation d'un autre point de vue (il n'y a pas de contre-champ cinématographique, venu bien plus tardivement), la comparaison des arguments signera la victoire ou déclenchera une 'belle'.

Ici la vue serait alors contre quoi?